# Xcode Naming Executables

Tags: iphone, xcode

Ok.

So I got my first app approved by Apple, it goes on sale this week.  With that out the door, I wanted to create a Lite version of the app.

I did a branch in SVN, and created a new working directory.

Original app is Trak4, Lite version is obviously Trak4 Lite

I noticed that when I build, the .app file that Xcode creates is still Trak4.app even though in the plist file, I've changed the Executable name to Trak4Lite, the project was renamed to Trak4Lite, etc.

In Products it says the Product is Trak4 Lite, but at the build step it's generating Trak4.app.

What am I missing?  Why is the executable name wrong?

I'm running OS3.0 GM.  I'm not running Snow Leopard yet.

Keith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For free versions of my apps, I create a second target in the same project, rather than creating a branch. After you duplicate the target, you just need to change the Product Name setting for that target. I also create a new Info.plist, and point to that in the target settings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the Product Name (PRODUCT_NAME) in your target's Build Settings, and you might want to point to a different Info.plist also.
[alt text http://web3.twitpic.com/img/13461715-4c0d84c623011739cca45f9b3f44abc3.4a3e605a-full.png](http://web3.twitpic.com/img/13461715-4c0d84c623011739cca45f9b3f44abc3.4a3e605a-full.png)

Answer (score 0):

I always get tripped up by that. I've used [Rename Xcode Project](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/17683) to help me out.